# Memory issues with libdispatch

Tags: grand-central-dispatch

I have been testing sample code from the wiki and found that libdispatch is alloc'ing a lot of memory without releasing it, both in OS X (Lion 10.7.3, Xcode 4.3.2) and Linux (manually compiled and installed).

The code creates a SIGHUP signal source, with a handler that calls 100_000 writes to a logfile. The write to a log is queued in a serial queue.

The first run shows normal memory usage (8-9 MiB both Linux and OS X). After sending a "kill -1 " memory usage increases 1-20MiB every time I send the SIGHUP signal.

I have tried compiling with -fobj-arc and without it, but the result is the same. I removed the NSString usage in the br_log function, but the leak is not there: it is somewhere inside libdispatch.

I tried both valgrind and Xcode Instruments, but no leaks are found. Thanks in advance,

```
//
//  main.m
//  test02
//
//  Created by Aldrin Martoq on 4/29/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#include <unistd.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <dispatch/dispatch.h>

static FILE *log_file = NULL;
static NSString *log_filename = @"/tmp/br.log";
static dispatch_queue_t log_queue;


void br_log(NSString *format, ...) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, format);
        NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:ap];
        va_end(ap);

        if (log_file == NULL) {
            log_queue = dispatch_queue_create("cl.martoq.log_queue", NULL);

            log_file = fopen([log_filename cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "a");
            NSLog(@"Log file created: %@", log_filename);
        }

        dispatch_async(log_queue, ^{
            @autoreleasepool {
                const char *c = [s cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                fputs(c, log_file);
                fputs("\n", log_file);
                fflush(log_file);
                [s release];
            }
        });
    }
}

void br_setup() {
    signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
    dispatch_source_t sig_src = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_SIGNAL, SIGHUP, 0, dispatch_get_main_queue());
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(sig_src, ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            printf("Caught SIGHUP\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                br_log(@"prueba: %d", i);
            }
        });
    });
    dispatch_resume(sig_src);
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
        br_setup();
        dispatch_main();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you measuring this memory usage growth? I cannot reproduce it on Mac OS X with the 'heap' tool.

You might be seeing the temporary effects of the libdispatch continuation cache, these are small buffers that get allocated for each dispatch_async() and cached on a per-thread basis for speed. That cache is freed once a temporary dispatch worker thread exits (a couple of seconds after SIGHUP in your example, on Mac OS X at least).

Also note that there is no need to dispatch_async() from your source event handler since you are already on the main queue at that point (the target queue of the source)

BTW, you have already asked about this on [libdispatch-dev@lists.macosforge.org](http://lists.macosforge.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/libdispatch-dev/) and I have responded there, please don't ask the same question on multiple fora at the same time.